# how to get length of multi array in one object

Tags: javascript

I have object like this (nodename)

```
{
  BGF: [
    'bgf-simulator-pn',
    'bgf-simulator',
    'bgf-simulator-2',
    'bgf-1-error'
  ],
  Baseband: [ 'baseband_2', 'baseband_1' ],
  CCPC: [ 'ccpc-emulator' ],
  CCRC: [ 'ccrc-emulator' ],
  CEE: [ 'cee' ],
}
```

I want get length of array key

I used this way

```
    const nodename = await topologyBrowser.nodes();
    const arrayLength = Object.keys(nodename).length;
    console.log(arrayLength);
```

and console log return 5, but I want 9,

what did I wrong,
what should I do guys

Comment: So, you actually want the combined length of every array property in an object?

Comment: @DBS  Yes sir, I want length of array property in object

Comment: why 9? Either you are asking the question wrong. Because the 5 is the length of keys after all.

Comment: @NicolasGoosen,  appreciate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```js
const nodename = {
  BGF: [
    'bgf-simulator-pn',
    'bgf-simulator',
    'bgf-simulator-2',
    'bgf-1-error'
  ],
  Baseband: [ 'baseband_2', 'baseband_1' ],
  CCPC: [ 'ccpc-emulator' ],
  CCRC: [ 'ccrc-emulator' ],
  CEE: [ 'cee' ],
};

const result = Object.values(nodename).reduce((res, curr) => res + curr.length, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`Object#values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and use [`Array#flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flattern the multi-dimensional  array.

Get the length like this: `Object.values(nodename).flat().length`!

See a working example-snippet below:

```js
const nodename = {
  BGF: [
    'bgf-simulator-pn',
    'bgf-simulator',
    'bgf-simulator-2',
    'bgf-1-error'
  ],
  Baseband: ['baseband_2', 'baseband_1'],
  CCPC: ['ccpc-emulator'],
  CCRC: ['ccrc-emulator'],
  CEE: ['cee'],
};

const res = Object.values(nodename).flat().length;
console.log(res)
```